# Is the last line from The Great Gatsby grammatically incorrect?

Tags: complex-sentences

> So we beat on, boats against the current, borne back ceaselessly into the past.

I am having a debate with a friend about the use of separated adjectival phrases at the end of sentences, and I used this sentence as an example of one. Is it proper to use separated adjectival phrases at the end of sentences like this?

This discussion arose around a sentence which I wrote:

> I was stuck, surrounded on every side by what seemed like the net forces of the Universe crushing me.

Though the adjectival phrase is somewhat more complex, it should still be as correct as the Gatsby quote, right?

Comment: That first sentence sounds fine to me.  Yours is not quite as poetic but seems OK.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite as eloquent as Fitzgerald, but I'm pretty sure they're using the same grammatical structure. I've been trying to figure out what exactly it is and I think it may be a trailing modifier.

Comment: Oh, the agony of futility; the obfuscation of complexity! Fitzgerald **symmetrically** nested two prepositional phrases within two short adverbial dependent clauses. (Though he omits the word, I can my feel my boat "*straining*" against the current.) @Zonedabone nested three prepositional phrases, with some triply nested clauses in one **titanic** adverbial dependent clause. (It's so hard to get my head around exactly WHAT is surrounding me, I forgot I was stuck. Grammar's good enough :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I should probably work on the phrasing a bit but I wanted to make sure I'm working with an actual sentence.

Comment: You are a good sport @Zonedabone. Keep up the good work. Someone needs to become the FSF for the next generation. May be you?

Comment: Thanks, I guess, though I'm guessing you're not recommending I turn into the Free Software Foundation? (I'm into CompSci so that might actually happen) Right now I'm just trying to get through my college application essays so I'm really grateful for the help.

I decided to skip the complex constructions and change the sentence to this:

"I was crushed by the forces of the Universe and buried by my flawed perspective." I think it better expresses what I'm trying to say anyway.

Comment: I just realized what FSF stood for. Now I feel dumb.

Comment: Isn't it preferable to allow the characters to speak organically, true to themselves, rather than to limit them to expressions that are, strictly speaking, grammatically correct?

Comment: An English professor of mine always pointed out that a 'diction'ary is, technically, a record of trends in spoken language. A word enters the dictionary only after it has entered into the vernacular. A word's grammatical usage is recorded in the dictionary as a reflection of how people have chosen to use it. Grammar style guides, likewise, are a negotiation between public tendencies and private preferences. The most important purpose of writing is communication, and there are certainly times when commonly accepted grammar can get in the way of communication. In those cases, choose for yourself

Comment: @Coty Johnathan Saxman, well said.

Answer (score 1):

It is "proper" and "grammatically correct." This is made clear by your question's title; it is *the last line from The Great Gatsby*.  And if you copy it to craft your sentence, then your sentence will be fine as well, though not as pretty.